# read class in javascript script index.html public folder react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to know how to embeed javscript script in index.html public folder file into react components. I already using this method but class still undefined.

```
componentDidMount () {
    this._loadScript('/library/es6-shim.js', false)
    this._loadScript('/library/fingerprint.sdk.min.js', true)
    this._loadScript('/library/websdk.client.bundle.min.js', false)
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.async = true
    script.innerHTML = "this.sdk = new Fingerprint.WebApi;"
    document.head.appendChild(script)
  }

  _loadScript = (src, type) => {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.async = true;
    tag.src = src;
    document.head.appendChild(tag)
    // tag.onload = () => this.scriptLoaded()

    console.log('headers', document.head)
  }
```

I need to read new Fingerprint.WebApi instance in my components.

Comment: Why did you comment out the `tag.onload` callback?

Comment: I think you can use their [fingerprintjs2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fingerprintjs2) npm package and follow GitHub 
 [docs](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2) for usage examples.

Comment: already using ```tag.onload``` but still cannot read that class/instance

Comment: hi @awran5, i think fingerprintjs2 is not for biometric fingerprint but for finger print browsers

Comment: Could you update your example on how you're using `tag.onload`?

Comment: Hi @Grabofus
here: 

```componentDidMount () {
    this._loadScript('/library/es6-shim.js')
    this._loadScript('/library/fingerprint.sdk.min.js')
    this._loadScript('/library/websdk.client.bundle.min.js')
  }

  _loadScript = (src) => {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.async = true;
    tag.src = src;
    document.head.appendChild(tag)
    tag.onload = () => this.scriptLoaded()
  }

  scriptLoaded = () => {
    this.sdk = new Fingerprint.WebApi;
  }```

I Don't know which lib that have Fingerprint class, cause it is lack in documentation

Comment: That way the callback will be called 3 times, after each load, let me post a possible answer. Let me know what you get, we can dig into it, if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Grabofus then how i know Fingerprint class is in where library? 

in my case, in documentation, i need all library as depedencies,

Comment: You can inspect the libraries, or just directly load with a `<script>` tag on your `index.html`

Comment: @rusli Abdul gani please how can i get the `fingerprint.sdk.min.js`  file? please am urgently in need of it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load all three libraries then you should have access to the globally exposed `Fingerprint` class.

```
componentDidMount() {
  Promise.all([
      this._loadScript('/library/es6-shim.js'),
      this._loadScript('/library/fingerprint.sdk.min.js'),
      this._loadScript('/library/websdk.client.bundle.min.js')
  ])).then(() => {
    // Fingerprint should be available on the window.
    console.log(window.Fingerprint);
    const sdk = new window.Fingerprint.WebApi();
  });
}
_loadScript = (src) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('async', 'true');
    script.setAttribute('src', url);
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = reject;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you....

its OK now, before i wrong for the path of lib,